# Having difficulties in finding error: Matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab, error-handling, coding-style, logic

My aim is to call this function into the pso code for minimization. 
actually im calling this code into another program(mfile),here

```
 v=0.1*x0; % initial velocity
 for i=1:n
 f0(i,1)=ofun(x0(i,:)); 
end
```

so what should i do, could anyone plz write me a code, so i can remove this problem. my aim is to minimize error using ITEA code, which im trying to do, im trying to find a that every time code runs, e_t have last updated value, not e_t=0.001 . 
I don't have `e_t`. If I'm going to initialize it, it will remain constant, but I need to change its value in the code.

Second, I'm getting this error

> Error using  .*  Matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in ofun (line 10),     f = sum(t'.*abs(e_t)*dt);

```
function f=ofun(x)
    Kp= x(1);
    Ki= x(2);
    e_t;
    d=0.001;
    I_ref=-1.1:d:1;
    dt = 0.01;
    t = 0:dt:1;
    e_t= I_ref - (Kp.*e_t +Ki.*sum(t'.*abs(e_t)*dt));
    f = sum(t'.*abs(e_t)*dt); % line 10
```

I want to write code for following equations

```
error= I_ref - (kp * error + ki*(integration of error));
```

I want to set `I-ref=-1.1-1.1;`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: sir this is the code im trying to run

Comment: You should at least specify (an example for) `e_t` and the argument you use to call this function.

Comment: sir my aim is to minimize e_t by using optimization code, but i dont knw how to write these equations error= I_ref - (kp * error + ki*(integration of error));

i want to set I-ref=-1.1-1.1; in matlab, i want value of e_t to change every time my codes run.

Comment: function f=ofun(x)
Kp= x(1);
Ki= x(2);
e_t=0.01;
dt = 0.01;
z = 0:dt:1;
e_t= 600 - (Kp.*e_t +Ki.*sum(z'.*abs(e_t)*dt));
t = 0:dt:1;
f = sum(t'.*(e_t)*dt); this code is running but i think its wrong

Comment: Please update your question with all relevant information instead of adding it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here `e_t` get's the same size as `I_ref`

```
e_t= I_ref - (Kp.*e_t +Ki.*sum(t'.*abs(e_t)*dt));
```

Then you want to multiply it with t

```
f = sum(t'.*abs(e_t)*dt);
```

But `t` is of a different size as `I_ref`. `t` has length 101, `I_ref` has length 2101.

Answer (score 1):

"Matrix dimensions must agree" is an error message that appears in this case in line 10 because matrix t cannot be multiplied elementwise with the e_t. Whichever matrix is smaller, I would probably add ones to the rest of it so that the result matrix is still able tone populated. Why are you transposing matrix t though? Good luck with your project!

```
function f=ofun(x)
%Define variables and constants- when you define e_t, why are you not multiplying dt elementwise?  Also why do you transpose matrix t?
Kp = x(1); Ki = x(2); d = 0.001; I_ref = [-1.1 : d : 1]; dt = 0.01; t = [0 : dt : 1]; e_t = I_ref - (Kp.*e_t + Ki.*sum(t'.*abs(e_t)*dt));

f = sum(t'.*abs(e_t)*dt);% line 10
end
```

Comment: sir that problem is solved, the main problem is e_t, im calling this function in another code, but as it run more than one times, its values remain constant  i.e 0.01,  i want it to store new value in it. my code                                  function f=ofun(x,e_t)
Kp = x(1);
Ki = x(2);
dt = 0.01;
e_t=0.01;
I_ref = 1.1; 
t = 0 : dt : 1.1;
e_t= I_ref - (Kp.*e_t + Ki.*sum(t'.*abs(e_t)*dt));
f = sum(t'.*abs(e_t)*dt);
end

Comment: I'm a little bit confused as to what you are looking for, but did you try a for loop with an If statement or a while loop with the condition to keep running the function until a new value variable has a value? I'll update the code.

Comment: actually im calling this code into another program(mfile),here              
     v=0.1*x0;   % initial velocity
    for i=1:n
        f0(i,1)=ofun(x0(i,:));
    end so what should i do, could plz write me a code, so i can remove this problem. my aim is to minimize error using ITEA code, which im trying to do, im trying to find a that every time code runs, e_t have last updated value, not e_t=0.001 .